# Not getting triggered on RxMoya

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, moya

Could someone tell me why the first code gets triggered and the second code does not get triggered? (Assume "someEndPoint" is working properly)

```
let provider = MoyaProvider<MyApiService>()
provider.rx.request(.someEndPoint).subscribe(onSuccess: { response in
  print("triggered")
}, onError: { error in
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

```
MoyaProvider<MyApiService>().rx.request(.someEndPoint).subscribe(onSuccess: { response in
  print("not triggered")
}, onError: { error in
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The difference between two codes is just to use "let" or not. I could not make "not triggered" printed in the second code and I can't see any network logs for the second code. I really want to know why it is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, you are creating *and retaining* the provider.

In the second example, you are creating the provider, then calling `request` but you aren't retaining the provider so it is deallocated immediately after the request is made and long before the server satisfies the request.

It takes a while for the network request to come back, and the provider needs to stay in existence until it does.